# How do I have a platform-dependent check and no -Wtype-limits warning?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I have code like this which is meant to target various compilers and platforms:

```
long value = obtainLongValue();
if(value <= 0)
   handleError();
if((unsigned long)value >= (size_t)-1)
   handleError();
size_t valueAsSizeT = value;
char* buffer = new char[value + 1];
```

Thechnically `size_t` can be smaller that `unsigned long` or the other way around or they can be of the same size.

On some targets both `size_t` and `unsigned long` are 64-bit and the code actually checks something and compiles cleanly. Yet on other targets `size_t` is 64-bit and `unsigned long` is 32-bit and for such platforms the check is meaningless - `long` is never long enough to overflow `size_t` - and so gcc emits a warning when used with `-WExtra`:

> warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]

gcc is technically correct on those targets, but I need this check in place just in case.

How do I keep the check and have this code compiled cleanly with gcc?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg AFAIK that's the recommended way to obtain "the largest value possible for `size_t`".

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, that's in my question.

Comment: Ah yes it is. I think I need my morning coffee (or equivalent)... :)

Comment: I think the recommended way is `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()` :)

Answer (score 3):

Use template and specialization:

```
template <bool = sizeof(unsigned long) <= sizeof(std::size_t)>
constexpr bool CheckLongLessThanMaxSizeT(unsigned long value)
{
    return true;
}

template <>
constexpr bool CheckLongLessThanMaxSizeT<false>(unsigned long value)
{
    return value <= static_cast<std::size_t>(-1);
}
```

Comment: That's impressive. Is there any measure by which this is not overkill?

Comment: @sharptooth how is it overkill in any way? If you don't know the types while writing but the compiler does templates are the solution

Comment: @Joe One way to look at it is ... it's a template and a specialization thereof just to get rid of compiler warning!

Comment: @sharptooth Specialization is C++' compile time if. Of course you could also try `#if ULONG_MAX >= SIZE_MAX`. Or a local `#pragma` but that is definitely worse, and compiler dependent.

Comment: I think this solution is short enough to be preferred to compiler dependent `#pragma`. A possible alternative may be to use a non constexpr temporary variable to stock *MaxSizeT* and hope than compiler doesn't see this *hack*.